# Issue in setting mongo ttl based on timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

Currently i am clearing data in mongodb on start of next day. ie; Jul 15 2020 00:00:00 Data is getting deleted from db based on the time. Here i am strugging in assigning proper time to expiresAt attribute to mongodb. Below is the code i am trying to set to mongodb

```
 const dateToString  = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/Helsinki" });
 const date = new Date(dateToString);
 date.setDate(date.getDate());
 date.setHours(0);
 date.setMinutes(0);
 date.setSeconds(0);
 date.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Below code, i used to set ttl:

```
this.connector.update(COLLECTION_NAME,
                                 { _id: id },
                                 { $set: { amount, expiresAt: date } },
                                 { upsert: true });
```

If used the above code, it will set expiry with 15-07-2020 00:00:00. Requirement is mongodb has to automatically clear document in Finnish time 12.00 next day. But since server is running with UTC time,
this is not working as expected. I am not getting where i am missing the point.

Can somebody help me to find a solution for the same? Ready to use moment or javascript Date property.

Comment: @Joe Server is running in UTC time, example; if i created document, document has to be cleared tomorrow start of the day, timezone is Europe/Helsinki. So when i checked 12.00 clock finnish time, data has to be cleared.

Comment: All datetime objects in mongodb are stored as UTC.

Comment: @Joe Yes, can you update the way we can implement the time? Becuase if i set to 12:00:00 to mongodb, in finnish time 3.00 AM , data will get cleared. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes that is correct, so set the expire at to 9pm UTC

Comment: @Joe Can you just update the code if possible, that might be a great help. Will be happy to use moment also. Also if we have daylightsaving, will this be a problem?

Comment: You could use adding timezone offset to the date you are preparing. [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: @ambianBeing Could you please update the code if possible?

Comment: @Vishnu the code you have posted is just a date with a locale and setting it to 00:00:00. How are using it in mongo to set the ttl. Please update that code in the question as well.

Comment: @ambianBeing Updated the code. please have a look.

Comment: You need to convert the expiration time from local time to UTC in your application and provide it in UTC to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The current offset of Helsinki (EEST- Daylight saving time) is `UTC +3` which `3 hours` or `180 mins` or `10,800 seconds` ahead of UTC.

Store the `expiresAt` the way you are doing `00:00:00` and since mongo db will store this in UTC i:e 3 hours behind.

Create TTL index on `expiresAt` for 10,800 seconds after:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "expiresAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10800 } );
```

Comment: here the problem is if we add expire after seconds, then let's say if I created document in morning, then it will get expiredAfter 3hours..

Comment: @Vishnu Erm, Consider this. If u create the document in the morning but you are explicitly setting `expiresAt` to midnight right (00.00.00).. so mongo will store it in UTC `2020-07-15T21:00:00.000Z`, 3 hours earlier. And then document will expire after 3 hours of this date field.